# Accelerometer for Lightsabers - slicing through the Dialog interfaces

Tags: java, android

I am doing a lightsaber app for fun.  I followed a tutorial to learn how to get information from the accelerometer to play lightsaber sounds.  It instructed me to have the Activity where I get the accelerometer data implement the `SensorEventListener` interface.

I have a custom dialog that I want to use which allows the user to select lightsaber options - blade color and hilt.

I'd like to move the custom dialog to its own class, but that requires the `MainActivity` class to implement another interface to handle the callback from the custom dialog.

It's my understanding of Java - albeit limited - that while you can circumvent the rules on implementing multiple interfaces, it's not a good idea. I mean, the point of the design of Java is to NOT have you implement two interfaces, so it feels like I've got a bad design, here.

So to recap:

- Must have accelerometer interface in main activity
- Want to have custom dialog interface in main activity
- Prefer to keep to the intended Java design of having main activity implement one interface

Relevant portions: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> on `customizeSwordDlg` for the dialog object I'd like to move to its own class and file.  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> on `m_sensorMgr` for the accelerometer object whose interface is implemented by the Main Activity.

[MainActivity.java](https://github.com/creedrogers/LightSword/blob/d5eb08a037fad6116e26ec7cbb0be5dd5c8cb713/app/src/main/java/crogersdev/lightsword/MainActivity.java)

```
package crogersdev.lightsword;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SensorEventListener {

  /* Accelerometer Fun */
    private SensorManager m_sensorMgr;
    private Sensor m_accelerometer;
    private final float m_noise = (float) 5.0;
    private final float m_clashThreshold = (float) 25.0;
    private final float m_swooshThreshold = (float) 8.0;
    private float[] m_lastX;
    private float[] m_lastY;
    private float[] m_lastZ;
    boolean m_xyzInitialized;

    /* Listeners */
    private View.OnClickListener m_viewListener;

    /* Buttons and Views */
    private ImageButton m_hiltBtn;
    private ImageButton m_bladeBtn;

    /* Sounds */
    private SoundPool m_soundPool;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> m_soundMap;
    private int m_humId;
    private boolean m_swooshSound;
    private boolean m_clashSound;
    int m_swordOnSoundId = 1;
    int m_swordOffSoundId = 2;
    int m_swordSwing1SoundId = 3;
    int m_swordSwing2SoundId = 4;
    int m_swordClashSoundId = 5;
    int m_swordHumSoundId = 6;

    /* the Light Sword State class object */
    LightSwordState m_swordState;

    /* Customize Dialog Stuff */
    AlertDialog customizeSwordDlg;

    private View swordOptionsView;
    private ImageButton m_dlgHilt1;
    private ImageButton m_dlgHilt2;
    private ImageButton m_dlgHilt3;
    private ImageButton m_dlgColorBlue;
    private ImageButton m_dlgColorGreen;
    private ImageButton m_dlgColorRed;
    private ImageButton m_dlgColorPurple;

    /* Animation */
    Animation m_animSwordOn;

    protected void onInflateObjects() {
        m_hiltBtn  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_hilt);
        m_bladeBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_blade);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        swordOptionsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sword_options, null);

        m_dlgHilt1       = (ImageButton) swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.hilt1Dialog);
        m_dlgHilt2       = (ImageButton) swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.hilt2Dialog);
        m_dlgHilt3       = (ImageButton) swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.hilt3Dialog);
        m_dlgColorBlue   = (ImageButton) swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.blueBladeDialog);
        m_dlgColorGreen  = (ImageButton) swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.greenBladeDialog);
        m_dlgColorRed    = (ImageButton) swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.redBladeDialog);
        m_dlgColorPurple = (ImageButton) swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.purpleBladeDialog);

        // SoundPool ctor: int maxStreams, int streamType, int srcQuality
        m_soundPool = new SoundPool(12, 3, 0);
    }

    protected void onCreateListeners() {
        m_viewListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            int btnId = view.getId();
            switch (btnId) {
                case R.id.btn_hilt:
                    toggleSword();
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_blade:
                    showBladeColorDialog();
                    break;
                case R.id.purpleBladeDialog:
                    m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.PURPLE;
                    break;
                case R.id.redBladeDialog:
                    m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.RED;
                    break;
                case R.id.greenBladeDialog:
                    m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.GREEN;
                    break;
                case R.id.blueBladeDialog:
                    m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.BLUE;
                    break;
                case R.id.hilt1Dialog:
                    m_swordState.m_hilt = 1;
                    break;
                case R.id.hilt2Dialog:
                    m_swordState.m_hilt = 2;
                    break;
                case R.id.hilt3Dialog:
                    m_swordState.m_hilt = 3;
                    break;
            } // end switch
        } // end onClick
        }; // end m_btnListener = onClickListener ...
    }

    protected void onSetListeners() {
        //todo: this is ugly ugly ugly.  please replace with something cleaner.  does the onclick from xml work?
        m_hiltBtn.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
        m_bladeBtn.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
        m_dlgHilt1.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
        m_dlgHilt2.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
        m_dlgHilt3.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
        m_dlgColorBlue.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
        m_dlgColorGreen.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
        m_dlgColorRed.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
        m_dlgColorPurple.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainsword_activity);

        onInflateObjects();

        onCreateListeners();

        onSetListeners();

        // TODO: make all of the initialization functions in their own little "do all" function
        // group similar to above

        m_bladeBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        m_swordState = new LightSwordState();
        m_swordState.m_isOn = false;
        // TODO: read from preferences here for defaults
        m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.BLUE;
        m_swordState.m_hilt = 2;

        m_swooshSound = false;
        m_clashSound = false;
        m_humId = -99;

        m_soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        m_soundMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordOnSoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swordon, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordOffSoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swordoff, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordSwing1SoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swing1, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordSwing2SoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swing2, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordClashSoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.clash1, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordHumSoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hum2, 1));

        // setup accelerometer stuff
        m_lastX = new float[3];
        m_lastY = new float[3];
        m_lastZ = new float[3];
        m_xyzInitialized = false;
        m_sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        m_accelerometer = m_sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        m_sensorMgr.registerListener(this, m_accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        // Animation loads
        m_animSwordOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.sword_on_anim);

        customizeSwordDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK)
                .setTitle("Customize your Light Sword")
                .setView(swordOptionsView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dlgConfirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "dialog clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    m_hiltBtn.setImageDrawable(null);
                    m_bladeBtn.setImageDrawable(null);

                    switch (m_swordState.m_hilt) {
                        case 1:
                            m_hiltBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hilt1_med);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            m_hiltBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hilt2_med);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            m_hiltBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hilt3_med);
                            break;
                    }
                    switch (m_swordState.getColorAsEnum()) {
                        case BLUE:
                            m_bladeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_blade_med);
                            break;
                        case RED:
                            m_bladeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_blade_med);
                            break;
                        case GREEN:
                            m_bladeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_blade_med);
                            break;
                        case PURPLE:
                            m_bladeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple_blade_med);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dlgCancel, null).create();
    }

    @Override
    // todo: consider moving all accelerometer data to its own class
    public synchronized void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent ev) {
        if (ev.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            getAccelerometer(ev);
        }
    }

    private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent ev) {
        float[] aValues = ev.values;
        float currentX = aValues[0];
        float currentY = aValues[1];
        float currentZ = aValues[2];

        if (!m_xyzInitialized) {
            m_lastX[0] = currentX;
            m_lastX[1] = currentX;
            m_lastX[2] = currentX;

            m_lastY[0] = currentY;
            m_lastY[1] = currentY;
            m_lastY[2] = currentY;

            m_lastZ[0] = currentZ;
            m_lastZ[1] = currentZ;
            m_lastZ[2] = currentZ;

            m_xyzInitialized = true;
        } else {
            float deltaX = Math.abs(m_lastX[0] - currentX);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(m_lastY[0] - currentY);
            float deltaZ = Math.abs(m_lastZ[0] - currentZ);

            if (deltaX < m_noise) deltaX = (float) 0.0;
            if (deltaY < m_noise) deltaY = (float) 0.0;
            if (deltaZ < m_noise) deltaZ = (float) 0.0;

            m_lastX[0] = currentX;
            m_lastY[0] = currentY;
            m_lastZ[0] = currentZ;

            m_lastX[1] = m_lastX[0];
            m_lastY[1] = m_lastY[0];
            m_lastZ[1] = m_lastZ[0];

            m_lastX[2] = m_lastX[1];
            m_lastY[2] = m_lastY[1];
            m_lastZ[2] = m_lastZ[1];

            double avgX = (m_lastX[0] + m_lastX[1] + m_lastX[2]) / 3.0;
            double avgY = (m_lastY[0] + m_lastY[1] + m_lastY[2]) / 3.0;
            double avgZ = (m_lastZ[0] + m_lastZ[1] + m_lastZ[2]) / 3.0;

            /** Conditions for sound playing */

            // High average value for all three last values means swinging, play swoosh
            // but don't interrupt if already playing swoosh currently.

            if ((deltaX > m_noise ||
                 deltaY > m_noise ||
                 deltaZ > m_noise) &&
                m_swordState.m_isOn) {
                // TODO: randomize the swing sound so it doesn't sound exactly the same each time
                if (!m_swooshSound) {
                    m_swooshSound = true;
                    playSoundSoundPool(m_swordSwing2SoundId, false);
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 620);  // delay = duration of sound should be 620
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // High negative delta from previous to current means you're swinging and then stopping, play clash
            if ((currentX < m_noise && deltaX > m_clashThreshold ||
                 currentY < m_noise && deltaY > m_clashThreshold ||
                 currentY < m_noise && deltaZ > m_clashThreshold) &&
                m_swordState.m_isOn) {
                // TODO: light up LED for split second

                if (!m_clashSound) {
                    m_clashSound = true;
                    playSoundSoundPool(m_swordClashSoundId, false);
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1340); // delay = duration of sound
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Sudden change in direction means a clash
            if ((Math.abs(currentX - m_lastX[2]) > 15.0 ||
                 Math.abs(currentY - m_lastY[2]) > 15.0 ||
                 Math.abs(currentY - m_lastZ[2]) > 15.0) &&
                m_swordState.m_isOn) {

                if (!m_clashSound) {
                    m_clashSound = true;
                    playSoundSoundPool(m_swordClashSoundId, false);
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1340); // delay = duration of sound
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
            // TODO: customize sensitivity - allow the user to figure it out themselves

            // TODO: block the laser fire?

            // TODO: make sure you get the "stab the ground" action from lego star wars

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_sword, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public int playSoundSoundPool(int sound, boolean loop) {
        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;

        if (!loop) {
            return m_soundPool.play(m_soundMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1.0f);
        } else {
            return m_soundPool.play(m_soundMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, -1, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    private void toggleSword() {
        if (!m_swordState.m_isOn) {
            m_bladeBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            playSoundSoundPool(m_swordOnSoundId, false);
            m_humId = playSoundSoundPool(m_swordHumSoundId, true);
            m_swordState.m_isOn = true;
        } else {
            m_bladeBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            playSoundSoundPool(m_swordOffSoundId, false);
            m_soundPool.stop(m_humId);
            m_swordState.m_isOn = false;
        }

        //Toast.makeText(MainSwordActivity.this, "Off!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void showBladeColorDialog() { customizeSwordDlg.show(); }

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (m_swooshSound) {
                m_swooshSound = false;
            }
            if (m_clashSound) {
                m_clashSound = false;
            }
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // todo: is this where we would close down the app on exit?  right now if you hit "power,"
        // to turn the phone off, the app continues to hum as if the light saber is on (which it is)
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // ignore
    }

    // NOTE: must implement onResume and onPause to deregister accelerometer listener call back
    // so that you conserve battery life and don't let the callback sit there waiting
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        m_sensorMgr.registerListener(this, m_accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        m_sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this);
        m_soundPool.stop(m_humId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your statement that Java "discourages" multiple interface implementations, is wrong. Java classes regularly implement multiple interfaces, and that is 'normal'. Consider `Arraylist<E>` which implements `Serializable`, `Cloneable`, `Iterable<E>`, `Collection<E>`, `List<E>`, `RandomAccess`

Comment: Oh.  I suppose this isn't really a problem, then.  Do you want to move your comment to an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where I got the idea that it was bad to implement more than one interface.  Being corrected on that point and taking the time to update the code accordingly, here is the working code - sans callback implementation:

SwordOptionsDialog.java: the custom dialog with a custom view and a callback implemented via `DlgIfc`

```
package crogersdev.lightsword;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class SwordOptionsDialog extends DialogFragment implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    private View m_swordOptionsView;

    private ImageButton m_dlgHilt1;
    private ImageButton m_dlgHilt2;
    private ImageButton m_dlgHilt3;
    private ImageButton m_dlgColorBlue;
    private ImageButton m_dlgColorGreen;
    private ImageButton m_dlgColorRed;
    private ImageButton m_dlgColorPurple;

    public interface DlgIfc {
        // 'ok' of 'cancel'
        void okClicked(DialogFragment dlg);
    }

    DlgIfc m_callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            m_callback = (DlgIfc) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement DlgIfc");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int btnId = v.getId();
        switch (btnId) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        m_swordOptionsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sword_options, null);

        m_dlgHilt1       = (ImageButton) m_swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.hilt1Dialog);
        m_dlgHilt2       = (ImageButton) m_swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.hilt2Dialog);
        m_dlgHilt3       = (ImageButton) m_swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.hilt3Dialog);
        m_dlgColorBlue   = (ImageButton) m_swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.blueBladeDialog);
        m_dlgColorGreen  = (ImageButton) m_swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.greenBladeDialog);
        m_dlgColorRed    = (ImageButton) m_swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.redBladeDialog);
        m_dlgColorPurple = (ImageButton) m_swordOptionsView.findViewById(R.id.purpleBladeDialog);

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.sword_options, null))
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        SwordOptionsDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

The now less cluttered MainActivity.java:

```
package crogersdev.lightsword;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SensorEventListener, SwordOptionsDialog.DlgIfc {

    /* Accelerometer Fun */
    private SensorManager m_sensorMgr;
    private Sensor m_accelerometer;
    private final float m_noise = (float) 5.0;
    private final float m_clashThreshold = (float) 25.0;
    private final float m_swooshThreshold = (float) 8.0;
    private float[] m_lastX;
    private float[] m_lastY;
    private float[] m_lastZ;
    boolean m_xyzInitialized;

    /* Listeners */
    private View.OnClickListener m_viewListener;

    /* Buttons and Views */
    private ImageButton m_hiltBtn;
    private ImageButton m_bladeBtn;

    /* Sounds */
    private SoundPool m_soundPool;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> m_soundMap;
    private int m_humId;
    private boolean m_swooshSound;
    private boolean m_clashSound;
    int m_swordOnSoundId = 1;
    int m_swordOffSoundId = 2;
    int m_swordSwing1SoundId = 3;
    int m_swordSwing2SoundId = 4;
    int m_swordClashSoundId = 5;
    int m_swordHumSoundId = 6;

    /* the Light Sword State class object */
    LightSwordState m_swordState;

    /* Customize Dialog Stuff */
    SwordOptionsDialog customSwordDlg;

    /* Animation */
    Animation m_animSwordOn;

    protected void onInflateObjects() {
        m_hiltBtn  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_hilt);
        m_bladeBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_blade);

        // SoundPool ctor: int maxStreams, int streamType, int srcQuality
        m_soundPool = new SoundPool(12, 3, 0);
    }

    protected void onCreateListeners() {
        m_viewListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            int btnId = view.getId();
            switch (btnId) {
                case R.id.btn_hilt:
                    toggleSword();
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_blade:
                    customSwordDlg.show(getFragmentManager(), "Customize Light Sword");
                    break;
                case R.id.purpleBladeDialog:
                    m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.PURPLE;
                    break;
                case R.id.redBladeDialog:
                    m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.RED;
                    break;
                case R.id.greenBladeDialog:
                    m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.GREEN;
                    break;
                case R.id.blueBladeDialog:
                    m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.BLUE;
                    break;
                case R.id.hilt1Dialog:
                    m_swordState.m_hilt = 1;
                    break;
                case R.id.hilt2Dialog:
                    m_swordState.m_hilt = 2;
                    break;
                case R.id.hilt3Dialog:
                    m_swordState.m_hilt = 3;
                    break;
            } // end switch
        } // end onClick
        }; // end m_btnListener = onClickListener ...
    }

    protected void onSetListeners() {
        //todo: this is ugly ugly ugly.  please replace with something cleaner.  does the onclick from xml work?
        m_hiltBtn.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
        m_bladeBtn.setOnClickListener(m_viewListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainsword_activity);

        onInflateObjects();

        onCreateListeners();

        onSetListeners();

        // TODO: make all of the initialization functions in their own little "do all" function
        // group similar to above

        m_bladeBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        m_swordState = new LightSwordState();
        m_swordState.m_isOn = false;
        // TODO: read from preferences here for defaults
        m_swordState.m_color = LightSwordState.bladeColor_e.BLUE;
        m_swordState.m_hilt = 2;

        m_swooshSound = false;
        m_clashSound = false;
        m_humId = -99;

        m_soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        m_soundMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordOnSoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swordon, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordOffSoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swordoff, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordSwing1SoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swing1, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordSwing2SoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.swing2, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordClashSoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.clash1, 1));
        m_soundMap.put(m_swordHumSoundId, m_soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hum2, 1));

        // setup accelerometer stuff
        m_lastX = new float[3];
        m_lastY = new float[3];
        m_lastZ = new float[3];
        m_xyzInitialized = false;
        m_sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        m_accelerometer = m_sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        m_sensorMgr.registerListener(this, m_accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        // Animation loads
        m_animSwordOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.sword_on_anim);

        // Customize LightSword
        customSwordDlg = new SwordOptionsDialog();
    }

    @Override
    // todo: consider moving all accelerometer data to its own class
    public synchronized void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent ev) {
        if (ev.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            getAccelerometer(ev);
        }
    }

    private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent ev) {
        float[] aValues = ev.values;
        float currentX = aValues[0];
        float currentY = aValues[1];
        float currentZ = aValues[2];

        if (!m_xyzInitialized) {
            m_lastX[0] = currentX;
            m_lastX[1] = currentX;
            m_lastX[2] = currentX;

            m_lastY[0] = currentY;
            m_lastY[1] = currentY;
            m_lastY[2] = currentY;

            m_lastZ[0] = currentZ;
            m_lastZ[1] = currentZ;
            m_lastZ[2] = currentZ;

            m_xyzInitialized = true;
        } else {
            float deltaX = Math.abs(m_lastX[0] - currentX);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(m_lastY[0] - currentY);
            float deltaZ = Math.abs(m_lastZ[0] - currentZ);

            if (deltaX < m_noise) deltaX = (float) 0.0;
            if (deltaY < m_noise) deltaY = (float) 0.0;
            if (deltaZ < m_noise) deltaZ = (float) 0.0;

            m_lastX[0] = currentX;
            m_lastY[0] = currentY;
            m_lastZ[0] = currentZ;

            m_lastX[1] = m_lastX[0];
            m_lastY[1] = m_lastY[0];
            m_lastZ[1] = m_lastZ[0];

            m_lastX[2] = m_lastX[1];
            m_lastY[2] = m_lastY[1];
            m_lastZ[2] = m_lastZ[1];

            double avgX = (m_lastX[0] + m_lastX[1] + m_lastX[2]) / 3.0;
            double avgY = (m_lastY[0] + m_lastY[1] + m_lastY[2]) / 3.0;
            double avgZ = (m_lastZ[0] + m_lastZ[1] + m_lastZ[2]) / 3.0;

            /** Conditions for sound playing */

            // High average value for all three last values means swinging, play swoosh
            // but don't interrupt if already playing swoosh currently.

            if ((deltaX > m_noise ||
                 deltaY > m_noise ||
                 deltaZ > m_noise) &&
                m_swordState.m_isOn) {
                // TODO: randomize the swing sound so it doesn't sound exactly the same each time
                if (!m_swooshSound) {
                    m_swooshSound = true;
                    playSoundSoundPool(m_swordSwing2SoundId, false);
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 620);  // delay = duration of sound should be 620
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // High negative delta from previous to current means you're swinging and then stopping, play clash
            if ((currentX < m_noise && deltaX > m_clashThreshold ||
                 currentY < m_noise && deltaY > m_clashThreshold ||
                 currentY < m_noise && deltaZ > m_clashThreshold) &&
                m_swordState.m_isOn) {
                // TODO: light up LED for split second

                if (!m_clashSound) {
                    m_clashSound = true;
                    playSoundSoundPool(m_swordClashSoundId, false);
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1340); // delay = duration of sound
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Sudden change in direction means a clash
            if ((Math.abs(currentX - m_lastX[2]) > 15.0 ||
                 Math.abs(currentY - m_lastY[2]) > 15.0 ||
                 Math.abs(currentY - m_lastZ[2]) > 15.0) &&
                m_swordState.m_isOn) {

                if (!m_clashSound) {
                    m_clashSound = true;
                    playSoundSoundPool(m_swordClashSoundId, false);
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1340); // delay = duration of sound
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
            // TODO: customize sensitivity - allow the user to figure it out themselves

            // TODO: block the laser fire?

            // TODO: make sure you get the "stab the ground" action from lego star wars

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_sword, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public int playSoundSoundPool(int sound, boolean loop) {
        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;

        if (!loop) {
            return m_soundPool.play(m_soundMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1.0f);
        } else {
            return m_soundPool.play(m_soundMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, -1, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    private void toggleSword() {
        if (!m_swordState.m_isOn) {
            m_bladeBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            playSoundSoundPool(m_swordOnSoundId, false);
            m_humId = playSoundSoundPool(m_swordHumSoundId, true);
            m_swordState.m_isOn = true;
        } else {
            m_bladeBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            playSoundSoundPool(m_swordOffSoundId, false);
            m_soundPool.stop(m_humId);
            m_swordState.m_isOn = false;
        }

        //Toast.makeText(MainSwordActivity.this, "Off!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void okClicked(DialogFragment dlg) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "okClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //private void showBladeColorDialog() { customizeSwordDlg.show(); }

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (m_swooshSound) {
                m_swooshSound = false;
            }
            if (m_clashSound) {
                m_clashSound = false;
            }
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // todo: is this where we would close down the app on exit?  right now if you hit "power,"
        // to turn the phone off, the app continues to hum as if the light saber is on (which it is)
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // ignore
    }

    // NOTE: must implement onResume and onPause to deregister accelerometer listener call back
    // so that you conserve battery life and don't let the callback sit there waiting
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        m_sensorMgr.registerListener(this, m_accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        m_sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this);
        m_soundPool.stop(m_humId);
    }
}
```